# Why do I get mypy no overload variant of "zip" matches argument error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting, mypy

I have a class with a method:

```py
class TimeUtilitiesTestCase():
    def test_date_and_delta(self) -> None:
        """Tests date_and_delta utility method."""
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        tdelta = datetime.timedelta
        int_tests = (3, 29, 86399, 86400, 86401 * 30)
        date_tests = [now - tdelta(seconds=x) for x in int_tests]
        td_tests = [tdelta(seconds=x) for x in int_tests]
        results = [(now - tdelta(seconds=x), tdelta(seconds=x)) for x in int_tests]
        for test in (int_tests, date_tests, td_tests):
            for arg, result in zip(test, results):
                dtime, delta = humanizer_portugues.time.date_and_delta(arg)
                self.assertEqualDatetime(dtime, result[0])
                self.assertEqualTimedelta(delta, result[1])
        self.assertEqual(humanizer_portugues.time.date_and_delta("NaN"), (None, "NaN"))
```

I am running strict mypy checks (configs [here](https://github.com/staticdev/humanizer-portugues/blob/858db670671bf54d18ffcbbf63a396be863e5f53/mypy.ini)) and I get the error:

```sh
error: No overload variant of "zip" matches argument
types "object", "List[Tuple[datetime, timedelta]]"  [call-overload]
                for arg, result in zip(test, results):
                                   ^
note: Possible overload variants:
note:     def [_T1, _T2] zip(*iterables: Tuple[_T1, _T2]) -> Tuple[Tuple[_T
1, ...], Tuple[_T2, ...]]
note:     def [_T1, _T2, _T3] zip(*iterables: Tuple[_T1, _T2, _T3]) -> Tupl
e[Tuple[_T1, ...], Tuple[_T2, ...], Tuple[_T3, ...]]
note:     <3 more similar overloads not shown, out of 10 total overloads>
```

If you want to fully reproduce the error you can clone branch `strict-mypy` with:
`git clone -b strict-mypy https://github.com/staticdev/humanizer-portugues.git`

I tried to change `results` from list to also being a tuple but this error doesn't go away.

How is my typing incorrect here?

---

**Editor's note:**
This issue can be reproduced with the following minimal example:

```
def bug_repr() -> None:
    ints = [1, 2]
    floats = [3.14, 2.72]
    strings = ['a', 'b']
    for numeric_list in [ints, floats]:
        for number, string in zip(numeric_list, strings):  # <-- error here
            pass
```

This gives the same error:

```
main.py:6: error: No overload variant of "zip" matches argument types "object", "List[str]"
main.py:6: note: Possible overload variants:
main.py:6: note:     def [_T1, _T2] zip(*iterables: Tuple[_T1, _T2]) -> Tuple[Tuple[_T1, ...], Tuple[_T2, ...]]
main.py:6: note:     def [_T1, _T2, _T3] zip(*iterables: Tuple[_T1, _T2, _T3]) -> Tuple[Tuple[_T1, ...], Tuple[_T2, ...], Tuple[_T3, ...]]
main.py:6: note:     <3 more similar overloads not shown, out of 10 total overloads>
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

You can reproduce this on [mypy Playground](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.8&gist=e721eb9b31cd45d06301726ed063f379).

Comment: If you are only looking for a workaround, `cast(List[Union[int, float]], numeric_list)` should do the trick.

Comment: @0x5453 Do you think it is a bug that I need to cast that?

Comment: I'm not a mypy expert but it does seem like a bug to my untrained eyes.  mypy can certainly determine the types of `ints` and `floats`, and I would assume that creating a list of heterogeneous types would simply `Union` those types instead of inferring `object`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using your minimum example:

The problem is, that MyPy infers a type that is too narrow, namely `List[int]` and `List[float]` where it then can't infer the type `List of something` for `numeric_list`. In general, there are problems with containers and static type safety when you put in different things. E.g., you put in a float and an integer, so how would the static analysis know what you are taking out? See [Docs on Variance](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/common_issues.html#variance)

But you can declare a more generic type, using [Union types](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/kinds_of_types.html?highlight=Union#union-types), to declare that it may contain several types.

```
from typing import Union, List

def bug_repr() -> None:
    ints: List[Union[int, float]] = [1, 2]
    floats: List[Union[int, float]] = [3.14, 2.72]
    strings = ['a', 'b']
    for numeric_list in [ints, floats]:
        for number, string in zip(numeric_list, strings):
            pass
```

Alternatively you can just declare it as a List (or Sequence) without specifying what's inside:

```
from typing import List

def bug_repr() -> None:
    ints: List = [1, 2]
    floats: List = [3.14, 2.72]
    strings = ['a', 'b']
    for numeric_list in [ints, floats]:
        for number, string in zip(numeric_list, strings):
            pass
```

But I'm not sure what type that would infer for `number` in the inner loop.

(Note, you can also use `Sequence` as a more generic type instead of `List`)